# extra alignment tab has been changed to cr

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I'm trying to create a table and I've got the error you can see in the title.

The (minimal) code is :

```
\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{%
|>{\centering}p{0.20\columnwidth}%
|>{\centering}p{0.19\columnwidth}%
|>{\centering}p{0.11\columnwidth}%
|>{\centering}p{0.17\columnwidth}%
|>{\centering}p{0.11\columnwidth}|}
\hline
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

The number of column is okay, the end of line also ... 
I also get an if I insert an \hline between the two lines

The error in this case is Misplaced \noalign \hline

So far, I could correct it by having the last column without >{\centering}.

Any help greatly appreciated :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `\arraybackslash` for the last column:

```
 |>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.11\columnwidth}|}
```

to restore the `\\` after `\centering`.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
  \begin{table}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{%
|>{\centering}p{0.20\columnwidth}%
|>{\centering}p{0.19\columnwidth}%
|>{\centering}p{0.11\columnwidth}%
|>{\centering}p{0.17\columnwidth}%
|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.11\columnwidth}|}
\hline
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would like to suggest that you use the `\newcolumntype` macro (provided by the `array` package) to define a new column type called, say, `P`. That way, the code needed to set up the `tabular` environment can be greatly simplified.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array} % for "\newcolumntype" macro
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1\columnwidth}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering  % better than "\begin{center}" and "\end{center}"
\begin{tabular}{|P{0.20}|P{0.19}|P{0.11}|P{0.17}|P{0.11}|}
\hline
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

[image]